# Unable to get customer name using \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context

Tags: magento2.4.4

I am in the processs of upgrading magento commerce 2.3.5 to 2.4.4p2

After the upgrade, I noticed the normal code used to get the customer name is not working

```
<?php 
namespace Wowshop\Custom\Block\LogginInfo;
class Customerinfo  extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
     protected $httpContext;

    public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
     \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
     array $data = []
    ) {
     $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
     parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCustomerIsLoggedIn()
    {
     return (bool)$this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
    }

    public function getCustomerId()
    {
     return $this->httpContext->getValue('customer_id');
    }

    public function getCustomerName()
    {
     return $this->httpContext->getValue('customer_name');
    }

    public function getCustomerEmail()
    {
     return $this->httpContext->getValue('customer_email');
    }
}
```

instead of returning the customer name, the function **getCustomerName** returns NULL

not sure what changes in magento2.4.4 that causes this code to not working

anyone know what need to change to be able to get the customer data

Update : I try to `var_dump($this->httpContext->getData())` to check if able to get what the value holds, I get this result

array(4) { ["logged_in_customer_id"]=> string(5) "24526" ["customer_id"]=> string(5) "24526" ["customer_group"]=> string(1) "6" ["customer_logged_in"]=> bool(true) }

Answer (score 2):

Default Magento does not return whole customer data from the `\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context`

Default Magento only return below data about customer from the `\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context`.

```
1) customer_group
2) customer_logged_in
```

For get other customer data from the `\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context` you need to do some customization.

There 2 way to get current customer data.

(1) By using the customer session.

```
protected $_customerSession;
    
public function __construct(
  \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
)
{
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
}

public function MethodName()
{
    $customer = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer();
    $customerName = $customer->getName();
    $customerId = $customer->getId();
}
```

(2) Set value in the `\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context` and then use that information later on.

1. Define plugin
2. Create a plugin as you defined in a di.xml
3. Use httpContext data in block/helper

**Step – 1:** Define Plugin
Please create a di.xml file in your custom module at path app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction">
        <plugin name="data-defined-to-context" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CustomerDataContext" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Step – 2:** Create a plugin class
Please create CustomerDataContext.php file in app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin folder.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context;

class CustomerDataContext
{
    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $_httpContext;

    /**
    * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
    */
    public function __construct(
        Session $customerSession,
        Context $httpContext
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession= $customerSession;
        $this->_httpContext = $httpContext;
    }

    public function aroundDispatch(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {
          $this->_httpContext->setValue(
              'customer_id',
              $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId(),
              false
          );

      $this->_httpContext->setValue(
              'customer_email',
              $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail(),
               false
           );
           return $proceed($request);
    }
}
```

**Step – 3:** Use httpContext data by Block/Helper

I hope this will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, will try this and let you know

Comment: @MohdFarhanBinRamli is it working for you ?

Comment: Hi @Mohamad Bharmal, yes its working and the issue has been solved, thank you

Comment: Hello @MohdFarhanBinRamli, glad to hear, can you please accept the answer so it's help's other.

Answer (score 1):

You can set customer name by plugin

vendor/module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction">
        <plugin name="customer-session-data-to-context" type="Vendor\Custom\Plugin\CustomerSessionContext" sortOrder="15"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Vendor\Custom\Plugin\CustomerSessionContext.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Custom\Plugin;

class CustomerSessionContext
{
    /**
    * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
    */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
    */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
    * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    }

    /**
    * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface $subject
    * @param callable $proceed
    * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function aroundDispatch(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        
        $this->httpContext->setValue(
            'customer_name',
            $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getName(),
            false
        );      

        return $proceed($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, will try this and let you know